# "The something who/that/which" or "something who/that/which"?

Tags: definite-article

Which one is correct:

> 1. The person who won the match was amazing/Jami
> 2. Person who won the match was amazing/Jami

Do I need to use ***the*** before ***person***?

Comment: As a learner, I think that you make something specific when you describe it. Thus, I would say "The person".

Comment: You are talking about one definite, specific person, so you use the definite article "the".

Comment: Yes, you need the the.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to them directly as 'The person', or indirectly as 'A person'. Just saying 'Person' isn't providing any context to who you are referring to.

Comment: Welcome the ELL. Generally we prefer our answers to have a bit more explanation, backed up be references and using standard grammatical terms. This is the kind of site that you can use for reference about a grammar question. http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article